# Вкладка, вызвавшая notification

Tags: javascript

Использую Notifications API для вывода некоторых уведомлений. Уведомления работают (если поддерживаются браузером и есть разрешение). Но возник вопрос, как отправить пользователя на вкладку, которая вызвала уведомление, при клике на нём?

То что есть callback onclick у уведомлений это ясно, но вот как открыть браузер и нужную в нём вкладку - не ясно.
Гугл не помог:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (typeof Notification !== 'undefined') {
  alert('Please us a modern version of Chrome, Firefox, Opera or Safari.');
  return;
}

Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
  if (permission !== 'granted') return;

  var notification = new Notification('Here is the title', {
    icon: 'http://path.to/my/icon.png',
    body: 'Some body text',
  });

  notification.onclick = function () {
    window.focus();
  };
}
```

Уточню, что `window` здесь ссылается на вкладку, а не на окно браузера

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28391223/872294

Comment: Всё оказалось достаточно просто. Спасибо.